# Puppeteer page.click CSS selector not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer

I currently have this two input tags in my DOM

1. `<input class="select2-search__field form-control">`

2.
`<input class="select2-search__field form-control">`

As you can notice, they're the exact same input tag with the same classes

However, I'm able to select the first one, but not the second one using `page.click()`

I tried doing something like the examples below:

```
await page.click("ul.select2-selection__rendered:nth-of-type(2)>li>input");
```

Also:

```
await page.click("ul.select2-selection__rendered>li>input")[1];
```

But none of these work.

In the Chrome Dev Tools console I used just to make sure `document.querySelectorAll("ul.select2-selection__rendered>li>input")` that I was targeting the right elements, and it worked just fine, the output was an array of two input elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all the elements (which will be `ElementHandle`s) and then call the `click` function.

```
let links = await page.$$('ul.select2-selection__rendered>li>input');
await links[1].click(); // the second element has index 1 (0-based indexing)
```